# CSS - simple animation with image

Tags: css

Hey i am trying to do simple animation with css, the image should go from bottom left to top left. I tried to do the following but it didnt work :(

HTML:

```
<div class='col-5'>
  <img style="margin-left: 0%; margin-top: 31%;" 
  src="\C:\Users\user\Desktop\website\static\kingjulien_iliketo1.gif"
  style="position:relative; top:420px; left: 32px;" width="480" height="270" 
  class="juliengif1"></img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-5{
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s 2; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
     animation: myfirst 5s 2;
     animation-direction: normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
0%   {margin-left: 0%; margin-top: 31%;}
100%  {margin-left: 0%; margin-top: 0%;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the update code. You can change the values from the animation and the positioning. Hope this will help you!

```css
.col-5 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s 2; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: myfirst 1s 2;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {background: red; bottom: 0px; top: 200px;}
  100% {background: red; bottom: 200px; top: 200px;}
}

@keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {background: red; bottom: 0px; top: 200px;}
  100% {background: red; bottom: 200px; top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-5">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped, but you used pixels and it meand that if i view this on other screen it wont be in the same positionlike different screen size

Comment: Then you can use something like [this](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/dPezeQ)